# Add Validation error in m2m fileld - Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, m2m

I would  like  to know how add a  validation error in  m2m field

**model**

```
ind_downton =  fields.Many2many(
    string=u'DOWNTON',
    comodel_name='s_downton',
)

@api.constrains('ind_downton')
def _check_number_med (self):
        for record in self:
            for rec in record.ind_downton:
                if (rec.um_ninguno
                    or rec.tranq_sed) > 1:

                        raise ValidationError(_( 
                            'We only accept numbers less than 1'
            ))
```

But when I write restricted values not show me the error in screen.

Is it possible to do this or is there an improvement way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with context. On the field in form view pass some context, check context value in name_get method

```
<field name="ind_downton" context="{'special_display_name': True}"/>

def name_get(self, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    res = []
    if context.get('special_display_name', True):
        for rec in self.search([]):

            if (rec.um_ninguno or rec.tranq_sed) > 1:
                res.append(rec.id, rec.name)
    return res
```